# Preload all components when lazy loading standalone components for routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, angular17, angular-lazyloading

With the usage of standalone components in angular 17, instead of using modules we can directly lazyLoad components. But the issue is how to preload in this case? Earlier when lazy loading modules we used this strategy: withPreloading(PreloadAllModules). Do we have an equivalent for that for standalone components or will it also work seamlessly for standalone components?

Example:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./components/home/home.component').then((m) => m.HomeComponent)
  },
  {
    path: 'standalone-sample',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./components/standalone-sample/standalone-sample.component').then((m) => m.StandaloneSampleComponent),
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./app.standlone-sample-routes').then((m) => m.STANDALONE_SAMPLE_ROUTES)
  },
  {
    path: 'standalone-sample1',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./components/standalone-sample1/standalone-sample1.component').then((m) => m.StandaloneSample1Component),
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./app.standalone-sample1-routes').then((m) => m.STANDALONE_SAMPLE1_ROUTES)
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

app.config.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules))
]}
```

Problem:
When user visits /home route, src_app_home.js bundle gets fetched. When user visits /standalone-sample route, src_app_standalone_sample.js bundle is fetched.

What I want?
When user visits /home route, src_app_home.js bundle is fetched, post that in the background the rest of the route bundles are fetched and kept as well, src_app_standalone_sample.js and src_app_standalone_sample1.js.

Earlier when were using modules instead of standalone components to attain lazy-loaading. This use-case was filled by the use of 'PreloadAllModules'.
Can we continue using PreloadAllModules or do we have some other solution for this use case ?

I looked into Angular documentation could not fine any relevant information in this regard.

Comment: Please, format the code you posted. Second, Standalone literally means that the component is standalone. There is no relevant information because it makes no sense. Since a component can be standalone or declared in a module scope, the _pre loading_ stuff isn't necessary anymore (if talking about standalone scopes).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the question(don't have enough reputation points). So this might not be the answer.

```
  {
    path: 'standalone-sample1',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./components/standalone-sample1/standalone-sample1.component').then((m) => m.StandaloneSample1Component),
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./app.standalone-sample1-routes').then((m) => m.STANDALONE_SAMPLE1_ROUTES)
  }
```

For the above code, when navigating to the `standalone-sample1` route, only the `StandaloneSample1Component` is loaded, excluding its children.

In `app.routes.ts` use:

```
 {
    path: 'standalone-sample',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./app.standlone-sample-routes').then((m) => m.routes)
  },
```

In `./app.standalone-sample1-routes` use:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', pathMatch: 'prefix', component: StandaloneSample1Component,
    children: [
      { path: 'route1', component: SAAComponent, title: 'SAA Component' },
      { path: 'route2', component: SABComponent, title: 'SAB Component' },
      { path: 'route3', component: SACComponent, title: 'SAC Component' }
    ]
  }
];
```